# Why is the commit necessary to handle the DateTime data correctly?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I am using:

1. [PostgreSQL 12](https://postgresapp.com/downloads.html).
2. [toasted-marshmallow](https://github.com/lyft/toasted-marshmallow)
3. [toasted-marshmallow's 2.15.1 fork of marshmallow](https://github.com/lyft/marshmallow/releases/tag/2.15.1) (this will, I believe, need to be installed manually)
4. Python 3.7.12

My requirements.txt is:

```
sqlalchemy == 1.2.7
marshmallow-sqlalchemy == 0.14.0
psycopg2 == 2.8.6
toastedmarshmallow == 2.15.2.post1
```

The sample code to reproduce the issue is:

```
import datetime 
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, UniqueConstraint, DateTime, TIMESTAMP, String
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker, relationship, backref
from marshmallow_sqlalchemy import ModelSchema
import toastedmarshmallow

engine = create_engine('postgresql://localhost:6000/mydatabase')
session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
Base = declarative_base()

class TheTime(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'newtable'
    __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint('id', name='thetimestuff'),)

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    start_time = sa.Column(DateTime, nullable=True)
    string_data = sa.Column(String(255), nullable=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.start_time}'

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

class TheTimeSchema(ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        jit = toastedmarshmallow.Jit
        model = TheTime
        
time = TheTime(id = 3, start_time="2022-08-18T17:18:00.000Z", string_data="Hello, World!")
session.add(time)
session.commit()

time_schema = TheTimeSchema()
dump_data = time_schema.dump(time)
print(dump_data)
```

The code as written will work and I will see:

```
MarshalResult(data={'id': 3, 'start_time': '2022-08-18T17:18:00+00:00', 'string_data': 'Hello, World!'}, errors={})
```

printed.

However, if I comment out `session.commit()`, then what will print is:

```
MarshalResult(data={'id': 3, 'string_data': 'Hello, World!'}, errors={'start_time': ['"2022-08-18T17:18:00.000Z" cannot be formatted as a datetime.']})
```

What I would like to know is why the other two fields work, but the start_time field fails. Why do I need to do the commit to have the start_time field handled correctly?

I figure there is documentation somewhere which mentions that DateTime fields need some special handling, but I have not been able to locate it.

Comment: From the error message I  am guessing  this  a type conversion issue and that without the `commit` `time_schema.dump(time)` is working on the string formatted timestamp instead of converted form from database.  Try `start_time= ...` with an actual Python `datetime instead of a string and see what happens?

Comment: Something like: `datetime.datetime.fromisoformat('2022-08-18T17:18:00.000') `. Assuming you are using Python 3.7+.

Comment: I agree with your assessment for what the issue is. The question is where is this behavior documented? I would have expected `session.add(time)` to do enough so this could be handled correctly. The add was sufficient for the other two fields, so why not time? Would the mishandling of time be considered a bug in one of the packages involved?

Comment: Hard to say. The first thing would be to step through the chain and see how the data changes inn the SQLAlcheny portion and then the toasted-marshmallow portion. I suspect it is the toasted-marshmallow part that is causing the issue. FYI, this is why I don't use ORMs anymore, too much time spent working out other peoples bugs and trying to game then to get stuff done.

Comment: From a quick look, I'm tempted to guess the other fields work because (de)serialization of int/str is trivial so even if it does not happen, there is no error (as opposed to datetime).

Answer (score 1):

In general, SQLAlchemy doesn't perform any conversion or coercion on the values set for column attributes. Rather, it passes the values as-is to the driver (for example, psycopg2) to construct an insert or update statement. If a `DateTime` attribute is set to a string value then accessing the attribute will return a string.

However, when a session is committed, any model instances in the session are [*expired*](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_state_management.html#refreshing-expiring)<sup>*</sup>, which erases their attribute values.  The next time that an attribute is accessed the database is queried to fetch its value.  The type of the value will now be of the expected type.

So in short, if you want the attribute to be a `datetime` instance before committing you need to convert it yourself.

---

<sup>*</sup> Unless the session has `expire_on_commit` set to `False`.